# RDL is taking very longtime to render the report

Tags: ssrs-2008, rdlc, rdl

In my report, I have 1 Tablix and **40 columns**, i am simply dumping my data into the report, Scenario is as follow:

1. First row is for heading of the reports.
2. In Second row, i have data bound columns.
3. In third row, SUM expression.

I have some **5000 rows** in my data table, This scenario is taking around **18 seconds** to render the report.

Now the problem is that I need to apply colors dynamically eg. 
**=iif(CellValue >= 0 , "Black","Red")** to all of my columns. as soon as i have applied this expression, report took around **5 mins** to render.

Kindly share you expertise.

Regards
Inderjeet Singh

Comment: Is this an SSRS report (server based), or a LocalReport (desktop app)?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes SSRS has a bit of trouble doing lots of calculations during rendering. One thing to try is to have this calculation done as a column in the SQL if you can. Then simply refer to this field to determine the color. If you can't do that, add a calculated field to your dataset so that the calculations are done at a higher level than cell-by-cell. That usually helps too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my personal experience I have found that adding filters within SSRS tends to slow it down. Based on your dataset though it should not have much problem. 
Additionally, if you have a grouping set to display pages on a single page (i.e. Keep together) that will slow it down as well.